# JSON parsing in Swift - data not available outside of the closure

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm new into swift so this might be a very stupid question:

I have the following situation related to parsing a very simple json file, everything works fine until I decide to use the data outside of the closure:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI



var numerolokas : Int = 0

// Function to Get all the XXX´s ID´s

func getLokasIds(completion: @escaping ([Int]) -> Void ){


    let headers = [
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxx"]
    let Url = String(format: "http://xxxx")
    let serviceUrl = URL(string: Url)
    var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let lokas_ids =  try JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: data)
                completion(lokas_ids)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }
        .resume()

}
```

Then in the code I call the function

```
    getLokasIds  {

        (lokas_ids) in

       numerolokas = lokas_ids.count
       print(numerolokas)
}
```

So far so good, but if for example I would like to use the variable "numeroLokas" outside of that closure its empty, and I don't understand why or how can it be done to be available.

Comment: Can you please provide an environment code where you call `getLokasIds` function?

Comment: If `numerolokas` is a class property you should be able to use it outside the closure but only once the closure has executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a completion handler to update the value of `numerolokas`. API calls are asynchronous i.e. code will continue to execute and put the API call in background and jump to the next lines of code.

The code between the brackets in `getLokasIds { }` will be called once the API response is received. So here you can update the value of `numeroLokas`. But if you try to call `numeroLokas` outside the scope of `getLokasIds` then you may or may not get the desired result depending on whether the API request has been completed or not.

```
getLokasIds  { 

    (lokas_ids) in

   numerolokas = lokas_ids.count
   print(numerolokas) // this will show correct value as its being updated after receiving response from api
}
```

Now,

```
getLokasIds  {

    (lokas_ids) in

   numerolokas = lokas_ids.count
   print(numerolokas) // shows correect value
}
print(numerolokas) // this print statement is outside the getLokasIds function and will show 0 as result because the api is still executing in background and numerolokas value is not updated yet.
```